# what's the difference between use of XQuery functions substring() between SQL Server 2008 and 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, xquery-sql

As per Microsoft new SQL Server version 2014 there is a difference in the use of [`substring` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178063.aspx) in `XQuery`:

> If the compatibility level is 110 or later, each surrogate pair is counted as a single character. For earlier compatibility levels, they are counted as two characters.

What does "surrogate pair" mean here? Please give some sample to explain this new feature in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it refers to [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) surrogate pairs, where two code units (in the range 0xD800 to 0xDFFF) encode a single character in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF.

I interpret the statement you quote to mean that earlier versions interpret each code point as a single character even if it's actually a half of a single character.

Using the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16),  (`U+10437`) is encoded as the two code points <kbd>D801</kbd><kbd>DC37</kbd>.  Older servers will treat each code point as if it were a character in its own right, and `substring` might even cut the two apart.

To take a concrete example, consider finding the third character in `"abcd"`:

```
substring("abcd", 2, 1)
```

- The older server treats  as two separate characters, and so the result is `"a"`.  (<kbd>D801</kbd><kbd>DC37</kbd>**<kbd>a</kbd>**<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>).
- The newer server recognises the  as a single indivisible character, and the result is `"b"`.  (<kbd>a</kbd>**<kbd>b</kbd>**<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>).

Comment: I am not clear with this surrogate pair. Would be great if explained through some example.

Comment: Thanks @Toby Speight , it seems that it was a bug in SQL 2008 whereas it has been resolved in SQL 2014 since now precision for calculating position of characters will be more accurate for UTF-16.